# Conversion is not correct in C program?

Tags: c

I have created this program, it converts miles into km but answer is wrong when i compare it with my Phone's result. But in program everything is fine.

```
int main(void) {

char i;
float km, miles;

do {
    printf("Enter Distance in Miles: "); scanf("%f", &miles);
    km = miles * 1.906;

    printf("Distance in KM is: %.2f \n", km);

    printf("Enter Y/y to continue or any other key to stop."); scanf(" %c", &i);
}
while( i == 'y' || i == 'Y' );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formula is wrong, the correct one is:

```
km = miles * 1.609
```

Answer (score 7):

Your conversion factor is wrong: there are 1.609 km in 1 mile.

More precisely, 1 foot is 0.3048 m (by definition), so 5280 ft (1 mile) is (5280 * 0.3048 / 1000) = 1.609344 km.

Comment: ...not to mention the U.S. Survey mile, which is 1.609347219km, or the nautical mile, which is 1.852km, or various other miles, historical and contemporary... which is why the smart ones use metrical. ;-)